# SharePoint 2010 PDF file not opening for a Single User

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

A user of SharePoint 2010 site is not able to open any PDF file with in the site.
PDF files are uploaded into document library and user is having contribute rights to the library. When user click on the document nothing happens. Other users with same access rights can open the PDF files.
This is high priority issue for us.

Please help me to identify the cause or resolve the issue.

Comment: Check in different browser or ask user to check on another machine.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. User is able to open PDF files into Firefox.She is only having issue in IE. I will check her IE settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can he open PDF before? Ask him if he had any update recently(eg. Adobe Reader update).

Make sure if an Adobe extension/add-on called "Adobe Acrobat SharePoint OpenDocuments Component" is enabled in this single user's IE. If yes, disable it and check the results.

Make sure if this issue is related to browser. You can let him test in Chrome.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. User is able to open PDF files into Firefox.She is only having issue in IE. I will check her IE settings.

Comment: Resetting IE browser has resolved the issue.